# admin_url() do not retrieve the correct url in an subdirectory install

Tags: wp-admin, directory

I have installed Wordpress locally in a subdirectory. I have the `admin_url( 'users.php' )` template tag in a plugin that retrieves the `http://localhost/wp-admin/users.php` URL instead of the `http://localhost/subdirectory/wp-admin/users.php`. How to solve this?

**UPDATE**

This is the function where the above template tag is used:

```
function get_some_url() {
    $full_url = add_query_arg( 'action', 'action-name', admin_url( 'users.php' ) );
    $relative_url = str_replace( get_site_url(), '', $full_url );
    return $relative_url;
}
```

Comment: Please check wordpress url and site URL in general settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by trying this (and it works!):

```
function get_some_url() {
    $full_url = add_query_arg( 'action', 'action-name', admin_url( 'users.php' ) );
    //$relative_url = str_replace( get_site_url(), '', $full_url );
    //return $relative_url;
    return $full_url;
}
```

This was tested in a localhost/subdirectory install and in a live install (not subdirectory). Now the URL is retrieved correctly.